# Billing block guidelines in various countries

Tags: posters

Recently read from Wikipedia that, there are certain specific rules for preparing [billing block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billing_(filmmaking)) of a movie poster. Such as *point size of the billing block is 15 to 35% of the average height of each letter in the title logo* and specific billing order which are maintained by [DGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directors_Guild_of_America) and [WGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Writers_Guild_of_America) in the U.S.

So my questions are

- Are these universally accepted rules?
- Does each country have their own billing block guidelines?